# GWT Compile every time I deploy to Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Everytime I deploy my project to appengine the GWT modules recompile(which takes several minutes).  This happens even if there are no changes to the code and I am only updating the server code.  How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick, I'm not sure why you are deploying to the app engine if you are not making any changes. Anyway, you could do the following:

Right click on your project -> export -> as war

When you create a war, this does not compile, and then you can manually upload the .war to the App Engine using the appcfg tool.

**EDIT:** it's not necesary to use the eclipe export, all you need to do is use the appcfg tool and build from eclipse.

Check [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Uploading_the_App) out for additional info on using appcfg to deploy.

Comment: I want to upload the appengine server files.  My GWT code has remained untouched and therefore does not need to be compiled and sent over the wire.

Comment: Oh ok I get it, still my answer solves your issue. Using eclipse's export feature never compiles gwt code

Comment: Got it!  I used appcfg like you suggested and worked like a champ.  However, why would I use export?  All I have to do is a build from Eclipse.  I think this is an easier way.  I was hoping to find a way to stay in eclipse, but the CLI works great.  Can you edit your answer to remove the exporting and I'll accept it?